# Разница ManualMap в версиях windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, code-injection

В чем разница между manualmap инъекцией на 10 и 7\8? А точнее, почему если инъекция происходит успешно на windows 10, программа крашится на 7\8? Что изменено? PEB вроде бы везде одинаковый, как и PE заголовки